# How to use ckeditor in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, ckeditor, handlebars.js

I am developing a crud application in nodejs using handlebars templating engine. Now I want to add editor like ckeditor or any similar kind of editor in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditior is a front-end plug-in that runs directly in the browser you use it like any other front-end js plugin here is an example

```
  <div class="entry">
   <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <div class="body">
  <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
   {{body}}
 </div>
</div>
```

in the json:

```
{
 title: "My New Post",
 body: "This is my first post!"
}
```

you can try it here: [tryhandlebar](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: For CKEditor 5 use:   `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.4.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Comment: is there any way to require() it